# get value in function

Tags: javascript

i want to get declare value **id_log** on array function to **var id_L**, how do that?

```
function editcashiersession(id_log,d,e){
  var vdt = $('h_dttm').value;
  var vdt2 = $('h_dttm2').value;
  var tbd = _gel('tblcashiersession');
  var tr = d.parentNode.parentNode;
  **var id_L = ('id_log');**
  var curcashiersessioneditorid = _gel('rowcashiersession');

  if (lastcashiersessioneditorid) {

     _destroy(lastcashiersessioneditorid);

       if (lastcashiersessioneditorid == curcashiersessioneditorid) {

            lastcashiersessioneditorid = null;
            d.value = 'Edit Log';
            _gel('sessi_errmsg').innerHTML = '';
            return;
       }
}
```

Comment: What do you want to do exactly? var id_L = 'id_log'; will set the text 'id_log' as id_L.

Comment: sorry, i want to edit form by id, can you help me?

Comment: Please take a minute for the SO Tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

```
var id_L = id_log;
```

That's what you want instead of

```
var id_L = ('id_log');
```

And double check your javascript because you're not closing an if statement:

```
function editcashiersession(id_log,d,e){
  var vdt = $('h_dttm').value;
  var vdt2 = $('h_dttm2').value;
  var tbd = _gel('tblcashiersession');
  var tr = d.parentNode.parentNode;
  var id_L = id_log;
  console.log(id_L); //delete this line after testing.
  var curcashiersessioneditorid = _gel('rowcashiersession');

  if (lastcashiersessioneditorid) { //You forget to close this if

    _destroy(lastcashiersessioneditorid);

    if (lastcashiersessioneditorid == curcashiersessioneditorid) {
        lastcashiersessioneditorid = null;
        d.value = 'Edit Log';
        _gel('sessi_errmsg').innerHTML = '';
        return;
    }
  } // I added this in order to close it
}
```

Also, lastcashiersessioneditorid is not set on your code.